# JUnit error testing and logging

Tags: java, junit, slf4j

I am testing in a JUnit test that a custom error is raised in certain cases, with an @Test annotation, and everything goes well.

```
 @Test(expected = MyCustomException.class)
 public void MyTest(){
    ...
 }
```

However, in my code, when I have such an error, I use a logger (slf4j) in such a way :

```
catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        LOG.error("My custom exception occured with {}", inputVar, e);
        throw new MyCustomException(inputVar, e);
    }
```

So far, the behavior is good. When I build my application with maven, all the tests are done. 
When the described test is done, the test is marked as passed, but I have a full stacktrace in my shell with a big ERROR in front of it.

My question is the following, is there a way to remove the logs when I run the tests (and therefore not to see it in the shell)?

The second question is : Should I even try to? Or should I just verify that all the tests passed, and not worry about a stack trace and an error when I see one while building my application? (changing my mind instead of changing the code)

Comment: You shouldn't try. I think you should try to test that you log it. Maybe, you want to mock logger and check behaviour... But than test fails your logs can help you to undestand what happens.

Comment: You're right, I may use a mock logger to check my logs, but I would do it in a separate test, that doesn't change the "issue" with this test.
You're also right for debugging, even if I would rather use a debugger near the test than using the logs in this context.

Comment: It's very uncommon to log an error *and* throw an exception. If the code throws an exception, the code catching the exception should log it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stacktrace is expected for that test. Therefore, it is fine that it is logged. All works as expected, so I don't think you should change anything. Especially you shouldn't change any code to make the test log look "nicer".

Changing code (maybe some "isTesting" flag) would only obfuscate the code and change the behavior between testing and production and that is exactly what you don't want when doing unit tests.

Comment: Changing the code is not an option because it works well, I was wondering if I could configure something somewhere in the tests.

Comment: You could do a runtine reconfiguration of slf4j to hide all log messages.  But that is messy and is akin to messing with a global variable.  Proceed with caution.

Answer (score 0):

I should notice, that you are using not best way to check exception. I think [jUnit rule](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html) is more applicable for you. Because you will have a possibility to check exception message.